# Statistically, how safe are para-motor craft compared to other GA planes?

Tags: general-aviation, accidents, parachute, paraglider

I know there are very well kept records for death and accident rates in GA aircraft, but I was wondering if there were numbers for para-motor aircaft that are easy to compare?

Comment: What kind of statistics are you interested in? accident per flight? accident per flight hour? accident by distance covered?  absolute accident number? all of them?

Answer (score 2):

In the US, there are no records kept nationally, because they fly under [FAR Part 103](http://www.usppa.org/federal-aviation-regulations-for-paramotors/far-part-103-preamble/), and are, for the most part, unregulated. Neither para-motors themselves, nor their pilots are required to be certified. Para-motors are not required to be registered. In fact, there is no actual government regulation *requiring* training of any kind to fly a para-motor. It is recommended, but not actually required.

There is no requirement to report accidents to any governing body, beyond those of the organization (flying club) the pilot may belong to.

Pilot certification -

> At this time, however, pilots of ultralight vehicles are not required by Federal regulation to be certificated.

Aircraft Certification -

> However, the FAA presently has no intent to require certification of these vehicles by Federal regulation.

Aircraft Registration -

> However, registration of ultralight vehicles will not be required by Federal regulation at this time.

Comment: You are correct. Class E is controlled not the same as Class G. You are not, however, required to report in to anyone in either G or E. Just that while in E you must have visibility of 3 miles. My bad, and it was incorrect information. I have simply removed it. It's not really relevant to the question asked. Up- or Down-vote as you wish. My gist was that since neither the pilots nor the aircraft are required to be registered, it would be difficult to maintain records of accidents.